# Is there a way to read a .hyper file in R?

Tags: r, tableau-api, hyper

I've a lot of .hyper files to work with. Most of the time I work with them using Python (using tableauhyperio lib), but I need to read them in R and I could not find a way to do it. Does anyone know some way to read hyper files in R?

Right now I'm reading the data in python and exporting them as csv to read in R the csv files...